# How does Eclipse persist created/duplicated launch-configurations? DialogSettings?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was wondering how Eclipse persists created or duplicated launch-configurations. 
(When I restart Eclipse after creating or duplicating a launch-configuration, the configuration is still there)
Does Eclipse use the `DialogSettings` to store this user-created information?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All launches however they are created are normally stored in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory in a `xxx.launch` file.

The format of the file does look similar to the `DialogSettings` file but in fact it is created by different code in `org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfigurationInfo`.

You normally access launches through the various `ILaunchXXXXX` interfaces, `ILaunchManager` being the main interface.

Answer (score 2):

Depending if your launch is a `Local file` or a `Shared file` (see the launch configuration tab "Common").

If it is a `Local file` the configuration is stored in your eclipse workspace:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches
```

If it is a `Shared file` it is stored in the bundle/path of your workspace bundles, as `.launch` file.

If you duplicate a launch it is stored next to the original, e.g. in the `.launches` directory for `Local file` or in your bundle/path for `Shared files`.